# Java Akka - How to write a Comparator<Envelope> for a PriorityMailbox?

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to create an `UnboundedPriorityMailbox` as described [in the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.4/java/mailboxes.html). To extend `UnboundedPriorityMailbox` my IDE (IntelliJ) forces me to `@override` the method `public Comparator<Envelope> cmp()`, which is not described in the docs. Also I couldn't find any example elsewhere how to implement this method. I know how a `Comparator` works, but I can't figure out how to use it with the type `Envelope` :-/

Here's the code:

```
public class MyPrioMailbox extends UnboundedPriorityMailbox {
    // needed for reflective instantiation
    public MyPrioMailbox(ActorSystem.Settings settings, Config config) {
        // Create a new PriorityGenerator, lower prio means more important
        super(new PriorityGenerator() {
            @Override
            public int gen(Object message) {
                if (message.equals(PoisonPill.getInstance()))
                    return 1; // 'highpriority messages should be treated first if possible
                else
                    return 0; // By default they go between high and low prio
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<Envelope> cmp() {
        return new Comparator<Envelope>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Envelope t1, Envelope t2) {
                return 0; // <-- HOW TO COMPARE t1 and t2 ?
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int initialCapacity() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a priority mailbox is to be able to assign different priorities to different message types.  An `Envelope` has a `message()` method on that returns an `Object` representing the message that is to be delivered to your actor (via `onReceive`).  Get the `message()` from each envelope and check what types they are and then assign the result of the comparator based on that.  If you are using a priority mailbox then you must have messages that you want to be treated with a higher/lower priority, so see if the `message()` is that type for one of the `Envelope`s and return the int according to the rules for `Comparator`